# C# Using ComboBox selection to PrePopulate TextBox's

Tags: c#, combobox, oledb, oledbcommand

I'm a very noobie programmer trying to write a small bit of software.

In this code I'm trying to PrePopulate text box's in a form with details from an OleDB Database upon a new selection of a ComboBox.

Basically, Clicking a name in the ComboBox will PrePopulate some text box's with details regarding that name.

The problem is that the code doesn't assign the values from the Data into the text box's. Instead the textbox's display "0" 's.

How do I get around this?

```
private void cbbEmployees_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int PayrollNo = 0;
        int AnnualHolidayEntitlemet = 0;
        int DaysTakenToDate = 0;

        string Query = "SELECT PayrollNo, AnnualHolidayEntitlement, DaysTakenToDate FROM [Employee] WHERE FirstName +  ' ' + LastName = ?";
        string ConnString = @"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\HoliPlanData.accdb;Persist Security Info=False";

        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnString))
        using (OleDbCommand GetAllcmd = new OleDbCommand(Query, conn))
        {

            conn.Open();
            GetAllcmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cbbEmployees.Text;
            GetAllcmd.Parameters.Add("@PayrollNo", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = PayrollNo;               
            GetAllcmd.Parameters.Add("@AnnualHolidayEntitlement", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = AnnualHolidayEntitlemet;
            GetAllcmd.Parameters.Add("@DaysTakenToDate", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = DaysTakenToDate;
            GetAllcmd.ExecuteScalar();


            txtPayrollNo.Text = PayrollNo.ToString();
            txtAHE.Text = AnnualHolidayEntitlemet.ToString();
            txtDTTD.Text = DaysTakenToDate.ToString();
            txtDaysRemaining.Text = (AnnualHolidayEntitlemet - DaysTakenToDate).ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: naturally. You havent assigned anything to the variables after the initial declaration. so it will always have your default 0 value.

Comment: in addition to that, your query will only ever return `PayrollNo` as you are running `ExecuteScalar`

Comment: Do I not assign them after opening the connection?

Comment: no. your parameters are just that, parameters. they are not assignments. Additionally, they are also not even being used within the query - meaning it is open to SQL injection. You have a half formed idea here

Comment: Clearly there is a lot wrong, thanks for helping. What would I use instead of ExecuteScalar?

Comment: And how would I assign them to what I want?

Comment: What parameter needs to go into your `WHERE` clause? are first name and last name different columns? you specify a where to multiple columns like that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104546/discussion-between-takarii-and-josh).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/users/5292801/takarii

Thanks to extensive guidance from takarii ^^.. as follows is a working solution for the question!

```
    private void cbbEmployees_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Query = "SELECT PayrollNo, AnnualHolidayEntitlement, DaysTakenToDate FROM [Employee] WHERE PayrollNo =" + Convert.ToInt32(cbbEmployees.SelectedValue); 


        string ConnString = @"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\HoliPlanData.accdb;Persist Security Info=False";

        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnString))
        using (OleDbCommand GetAllcmd = new OleDbCommand(Query, conn))
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            conn.Open();
            dt.Load(GetAllcmd.ExecuteReader());
            conn.Close();

             txtPayrollNo.Text = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
             txtAHE.Text = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
             txtDTTD.Text = dt.Rows[0][2].ToString();


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

my code sample uses the data of the first found record.

you can adjust your query with select Top 1 ....
to be sure that you have the right record.

If your resultset can consist of more than one record you have to handle that in a while (oleDR.Read())
                    {
                        // do something
                    }

Comment: Already worked out an answer for this buddy, can't mark it as an answer for 2 days, thanks for the support though!

Comment: You can accept the answer in less than 2 days ( > 15 minutes) as long as it is not yours

Comment: Select top 1 would not guarantee the correct record (not to mention not being part of the OleDB keyword set). What if Matt Smith is a name used multiple times in the database? the query in your answer does not account for this in the slightest.

Answer (score -1):

```
private void cbbEmployees_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int PayrollNo = 0;
        int AnnualHolidayEntitlemet = 0;
        int DaysTakenToDate = 0;

        string Query = "SELECT TOP(1) PayrollNo, AnnualHolidayEntitlement, DaysTakenToDate FROM [Employee] WHERE FirstName" +  "' '" + "LastName = @param";
        string ConnString = @"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\HoliPlanData.accdb;Persist Security Info=False";

        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnString))
        using (OleDbCommand GetAllcmd = new OleDbCommand(Query, conn))
        {

            conn.Open();
            GetAllcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param", cbbEmployees.Text);


            //GetAllcmd.ExecuteScalar(); use GetAllcmd.ExecuteReader() instead
            OleDbDataReader oleDR;
                    oleDR = GetAllcmd.ExecuteReader();
                    if (oleDR.HasRows)
                    {
                         txtPayrollNo.Text = oleDR["PayrollNo"].ToString();
                         txtAHE.Text = oleDR["AnnualHolidayEntitlemet"].ToString();
                         txtDTTD.Text = oleDR["DaysTakenToDate"].ToString();
                         txtDaysRemaining.Text = (oleDR["AnnualHolidayEntitlemet"] - oleDR["DaysTakenToDate"]).ToString();

                    }


        }
    }
```

Comment: What if the query returns multiple rows? With the query as it is, you could have multiple people with the same name. not to mention the parameters in this case are totally unneeded

Comment: takarii you are right. BUt the sample lets assume that first and lastname are enough to identify a unique person. the select has to be so that you can expect ontly one record as result. If on the other side the input allows duplicate input of one and the same person you have to branch if the datareader has more than one record into an error handler.

Comment: Never make assumptions. The OP said he was new to this, and its a glaring error in logic. It is far better to educate and provide a complete solution than it is to let someone continue thinking it is a good idea